# 404 Custom is blank with asp extension

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

My 404 Custom setup shows up as a blank page if it has an asp extension. If I change the extension of the custom error page to .html, the custom error page shows correctly.

this is my web.config file

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" existingResponse="Auto">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />                
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error_pages/error500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" prefixLanguageFilePath=""  path="/error_pages/error404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
```

I cant figure this out... driving me nuts

Comment: So, when the requesting the asp error page directly in the browser it works and returns a 200 status? What happens if you change `existingResponse="Replace" `

Comment: Requesting the page directly works perfectly fine. I changed to "Replace", still the same.  Can it have something to do with asp cache?

Comment: I don't think it's a cache issue. Try adding `Response.Flush()` at the end of your error asp page. Also maybe Failed Request Tracing in IIS may be helpful.

Comment: Response.flush didnt work either... the funny thing is that there is no redirect, it would seem as the non existing page, indeed exists but is blank.

Comment: did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you like to redirect when the error happens, use...

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/time.asp" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
```

You may also hide the redirection, by using...

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/time.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

You can also use Custom Errors (of ASP.NET) like so...

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
        <error redirect="time.asp" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Works only if I rename the custom 404 file to something different than asp. This is baffling !b My site is running ASP Classic, not .net. Application Pool is running classic.

Comment: Can you browse to the ASP page directly?

Comment: Also, did you try getting a fiddler trace? Get a fiddler trace and send it to rahul@attosol.com if you would like to. On the server side, you should enable Failed Request tracing and capture everything at the same time. Last but not the least, check your IIS Logs and share the requests.